# Did Soldier Boy serve in WW II as Supe?

Tags: the-boys

Maybe I am asking this question too early as I haven't finished season 3 of *The Boys*, but I am wondering about the origins of the Soldier Boy:

In one of the episodes, we can see Frenchie and Kimiko watching a show about Soldier Boy - the doco shows a black and white war movie with the S.B. in the trenches rallying his men to "kill some krauts". But is he a superhero there already?

We know that Supes can have a long life (Stormfront is over 100) but Vought, the inventor of the power-giving "Compound V" was German and didn't defect to the Allies until almost the end of World War II. So while it is possible that he was converted before the end of the war, the time frame for it is a little short.

So was he Supe already during the war or did it happen afterwards?